# Appearing to be on the same network

Tags: networking, ssh-tunneling, openvpn

I have a user that needs to connect to a machine located on a private network at another facility.

Basically

```
192.168.0.20 -> 192.168.0.1 -> Internet -> 192.168.1.1 -> 192.168.2.1 -> 192.168.2.5
```

I can use OpenVPN, but apparently, the machine 192.168.2.5 needs to make new connections back to 192.168.0.20 as well as 192.168.0.20 making new connections to 192.168.2.5.

Is there any way to set this up through an SSH tunnel to give the appearance that the two end machines are on the same network?  I guess I could do OpenVPN in both directions (which I don't necessarily want to do).

Comment: Assuming it's possible to initiate ssh from 192.168.0.20 to 192.168.1.1, then it's possible to create a tunnel that listens for, say, ssh requests on 192.168.1.1 and routes them transparently back to 192.168.0.20. Is that what you're after?

Comment: `192.168.0.0/16` addresses are not routed in the public internet and you can't reach the other side. It would work if both Internet-facing machines had public addresses. But I doubt there's a way if both machines only have private addresses.

Comment: What makes you think an openVPN connection is not bidirectional? If 192.168.0.20 can reach 192.168.2.5 via the openVPN tunnel, when 192.168.2.5 can reach 192.168.0.20 barring any firewalling (which is out of scope for openVPN).